# Meaning of unique_ptr<const T>

Tags: c++11

Why `unique_ptr` can take owership of a `const ptr`?

What is the meaning of `unique_ptr<const T>`?

```
  std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int);
  // Only this is compile error.                                 
  std::unique_ptr<int> b((const int*)new int);
  std::unique_ptr<const int> c(new int);
  // Why unique_ptr can take a const ptr, and delete it when deconstruct?
  std::unique_ptr<const int> d((const int*)new int);
```

Tested with g++ 4.8

Comment: Same meaning of `const int*`, I suppose

Comment: @Casey stealth edit... That was originally `int * const`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why unique_ptr can take owership of a const ptr?

Because even constant variables need to be destructed and freed when they are not longer needed. memory and resources leak happens on un-finalized variables regardless the `const` or `volatile` keywords.

> What is the meaning of unique_ptr < const T>

Any meaning that `uniqe_ptr<T>` has , except it's `const T` and not `T`.

> // Why unique_ptr can take a const ptr, and delete it when
>   deconstruct?

I have a feeling that you think that `const` object cannot be deleted, since they are `const` hence un-modifiable and un-destructable. this is wrong. the `const` kicks in after the variable has being constructed and "stop" taking affect on the variable destruction. otherwise, you couldn't create any `const` variable neither destroy them.